# Inner widget not rebuilding when popping to previous page

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

First page has `onTapFunction` with logic to open second page and rebuid itself when popping back from the second page. The problem is that the InnerWidget doesn't rebuildidng when popping back.

The idea is to pop back on first page and rebuild the whole content. Don't want to use pushReplacement yet as it breaks the navigation flow.

The output when pop back to first page

```
I/flutter ( 3675): ---------------reLoadPage: true
I/flutter ( 3675): -------------building outer----------
```

i.e. the building of the inner page does not occur in this case

Why doesn't it work in this case?

```
class FirstPage extends StatefulWidget {...}

class _FirstPageState extends State<FirstPage> {
  onTapFunction(BuildContext context) async {
    final reLoadPage = await Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => const SecondPage(), //second page
      ),
    );

    debugPrint('---------------reLoadPage: $reLoadPage'); //true

    if (reLoadPage) {
      setState(() {}); // this setState doesn't rebuild InnerWidget
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    debugPrint('-------------building outer----------'); //true
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        actions: [
          IconButton(
              ...
              onPressed: () {
                // go to the second page
                onTapFunction(context); 
              },
            ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          ...
          //this doesn't rebuild on setState()
          const InnerWidget(), 
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class InnerWidget extends StatefulWidget {...}

class _RapportListState extends State<InnerWidget> {
  ...

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    load().then(
      (_) {
        setState(() { });
      },
    );
    debugPrint('end init');
  }

  Future<void> load() async {
    debugPrint('async load() start');
    ...
    debugPrint('async load() finished');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    debugPrint('building inner widget...');
    ...
  }
}

// on second page there is a submit button
onPressed: () {
  if (snapshot.hasData) { // true
    Navigator.pop(context, true);
  }
}
```

Comment: I think instead of providing new key/removing const, `InnerWidget`'s will have its won mechanism to handle it its state,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

flutter is smart enough to rebuild widget. As per my knowledge, when we call `setState()` it will re-execute the `build` method. but only widget that marked as dirty and set new `ValueKey` to the widget, then it will be rebuild.

so when we use `const` to the widget, it will not marked as dirty widget. Flutter will not rebuild that widget.

for example:

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   ....
  body: Column(
        children: [
          ...
          const InnerWidget(),  // this widget will not rebuild
          SomeWidget() // this is not use const, will rebuild
        ],
      ),
}
```

also you can force to rebuild any widget by give it different key

```
 InnerWidget(
    key: UniqueKey(),    
 ),  // no matter what, this will always rebuild every setState called.
```

##### Read this documentation for more detail : https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/Key-class.html